# Dynamically generate bar plot graph with Python 3 and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this Python 3 script that uses the 'collections' module to simply print out common words in a block of text and the number of times those words appear in that text.

```
    word_counter = collections.Counter(text)
    for word, count in word_counter.most_common(10):
       print(word, ": ", count)
```

For example, it may print this out:

- red : 5
- sun : 2
- planet: 10
- moon : 7
- hydrogen : 22

I have another script that uses the matplotlib library and generates a bar plot graph:

```
    words = ('red', 'Sun', 'planet', 'moon', 'hydrogen')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(words))
    wordCount = [5,2,10,7,22]
    plt.bar(y_pos, wordCount, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, words)
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title('Common Word Count')
    plt.savefig('wordcount.png')
    plotImage = "wordcount.png"
    htmldata = """
    <div>
        <img src="{plotImage}" />
    </div>""".format(plotImage = plotImage)
    print(htmldata)
```

So you can see I put static data in the that script for the words and the wordCount.

Is there a way to combine the two scripts I have so that they work together?  So the "words" and "wordCount" variable would be populated with data from the 'for word, count...' loop?

That way I could feed it whatever text or paragraph I wanted and not have to hard-code any values.

I tried to add these two lines under the 'for word, count ... ' loop:

```
myWords = myWords + word + ","
myCount += [count]
```

But that throws this error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single
>   shape

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177504/individually-labeled-bars-for-bar-graphs-in-matplotlib-python

Comment: `myCount` is not defined. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)